Python skips recursion if yield is present
I have the following XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" xmlns:okp="okapi-framework:xliff-extensions" xmlns:its="http://www.w3.org/2005/11/its" xmlns:itsxlf="http://www.w3.org/ns/its-xliff/" its:version="2.0">
<file original="temp/file_conversion/tmp4a9kn6bn/69502fea-751c-4c3c-a38a-4fce9e13ebde.txt" source-language="en" target-language="ar" datatype="x-text/plain" okp:inputEncoding="UTF-8">
<body>
<trans-unit id="1idhasofh" xml:space="preserve">
<source xml:lang="en">foo<bpt id="0">&lt;bar&gt;</bpt>&lt;Instruction><ept id="0">&lt;crow&gt;</ept>&lt;grande&gt;</source>
<target xml:lang="ar">foo<bpt id="0">&lt;bar&gt;</bpt>&lt;Instruction><ept id="0">&lt;crow&gt;</ept>&lt;grande&gt;</target>
</trans-unit>
</body>
</file>
</xliff>

I'm trying to create a function that parses an XML file that I've read into an ElementTree.Element:
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def parse_xml(ele: ET.Element):
    tag = ele.tag
    if not isinstance(tag, str) and tag is not None:
        return
    t = ele.text
    if t:
        yield t
    for e in ele:
        parse_xml(e)
        t = e.tail
        if t:
            yield t

def main():
    fp = "path/to/xml"
    tree = ET.parse(fp)
    root = tree.getroot()

    t_units = root.findall(".//{*}trans-unit")
    for source, target in t_units:
        for ele in parse_xml(source):
            print(ele)

I get:
foo
<Instruction>
<grande>

In my debugger, I see that parse_xml(e) gets skipped. When I replace the yields with print statements:
def parse_xml(ele: ET.Element):
    tag = ele.tag
    if not isinstance(tag, str) and tag is not None:
        return
    t = ele.text
    if t:
        print(t)
    for e in ele:
        parse_xml(e)
        t = e.tail
        if t:
            print(t)

I get the expected result (reaches all the tagged text):
foo
<bar>
<Instruction>
<crow>
<grande>

Why does this happen with yield?

You have a recursive call that will be visible in prints, but will not yield its values to top level. Try adding yield from parse_xml(e)

Recursion does not magically skip to the top level. Just like when returning, it only passes its values to the function directly calling it, in this case, parse_xml again. Which does not do anything with yielded value.
